# Tiles not working with spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, tiles

I have added tiles in my project but it is not working as. I have added footer. But footer and header do not show in the output. I only get the output

```
hello ...........................
```

But I do not get the content of footer in the output. How can I make tiles work? Thanks in advance.

In my layout folder I have classic.jsp and footer.jsp.

classic.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
</head>
<body>

    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />

</body>
</html>
```

footer.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

&copy; Test
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

hello ...........................
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="cz.jiripinkas.jba.controller" />

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

general.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/layout/classic.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="index" extends="common">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Java Blog Aggregator" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

and IndexController

```
package cz.jiripinkas.jba.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: My code here https://github.com/shiblybcc/blog-aggregator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked for me. I had to upgrade my apache tiles version to current version.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("index") ;
    }
```

so rteurn ModelAndView Instead of String.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest the code should be changed to this

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"
value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />

<bean id= "viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You return wrong value in `IndexController`, your `IndexController` directs to `index.jsp`, which is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

hello ...........................
```

It just outputs `hello ...........................`, right?

Try:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/classic")
    public String classic() {
        return "classic";
    }
}
```